# Facebook Messenger Opt In button only appears sometimes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am trying to put a facebook messenger 'send to messenger' button onto my site. So far, I have been making changes, and the button appears occasionally, but most of the time it doesn't.

The code I've got to load it is here:

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: Meteor.settings.public.FacebookAppId,
        xfbml: true,
        version: "v2.6"
      });
      console.log('something in the fb init worked')
    FB.Event.subscribe('send_to_messenger', function(e) {
        console.log("messenger_checkbox event");
        console.log(e);
        if (e.event == 'rendered') {
            console.log("Plugin was rendered");
        } else if (e.event == 'not_you') {
            console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
        } else if (e.event == 'hidden') {
            console.log("Plugin was hidden");
        }
    });
    if (typeof (FB) != 'undefined'&& FB != null) { FB.XFBML.parse(); }
    console.log('This then worked as well')
    };
    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  <div class='react' id="react-root"></div>
</body>
```

It seems the FB.Event.subscribe function isn't being called either whenever the button doesn't load.

The code to load the actual button is here:

```
        <div className="fb-send-to-messenger"
          data-messenger_app_id={Meteor.settings.public.FacebookAppId}
          data-page_id={Meteor.settings.public.FacebookPageId}
          data-ref="PASS_THROUGH_PARAM"
          data-color="blue"
          data-size="standard">
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve this exactly, but using [this react-messenger-plugin package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-messenger-plugin) instead of the `<div>` above did mean the button always appeared.